# Image Capture & Analysis iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

I'm having a bit of a headache with this. I am using the iPhone to camera to capture live images using AVFoundation. In the captureOutput function I am creating a UIImage from the sampleBuffer as per apples developer notes - if I save this image to the camera roll I can view it and it looks as it expected (I am not doing this every time captureOutput is called!). However I do not want to save it - instead I want to have a look at some of its pixel values.

So again using apples notes I am get pixel values at X & Y points. I also noted that the colour order is BGRA (not RGBA) so I can get these values and they all look OK only they appear to be wrong...

If I save the exact same image to the camera roll, email it to myself, then put it into my xcode project so I can create a UIImage from this in my App which I can then pass through the exact same set of methods I get a different set of figures for the pixel RGB data (I did switch back to RGBA for this image but even allowing for BGRA being wrong the numbers don't match) - to confirm I created the same routines on a PC using C# used the same image and got the same figures.

Is there a difference between a UIImage created in memory and one that is then saved and reloaded?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Hey there!  I just stumbled onto your question.  I recently read part 1 and 2 of this article https://www.raywenderlich.com/69855/image-processing-in-ios-part-1-raw-bitmap-modification, please have a look.  I think it will answer your question.  Cheers.